# consumer producer with blocking collection exception handling

Tags: .net, vb.net, task-parallel-library

This is a situation where there is always more work to be done since there is always a queue of emails to process. I want to make sure that any exceptions produced in the parallel.foreach will be logged. The examples I've found all wait until the queue (in this case MailToDownload) is finished before I can handle the exceptions. In my situation, how should I handle exceptions?

Below is a basic example of how I'm writing my methods. The first task pulls a list of emails to be pulled from the database. Every time an email account gets mail, the email address is inserted into the table, so there is always data.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim MailToDownload As New BlockingCollection(Of myMail)

    Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub()
                            For i As Integer = 0 To 99
                                MailToDownload.Add(New myMail With {.id = i})
                                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
                            Next
                          End Sub)

    Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub()
                            Dim options As ParallelOptions = New ParallelOptions With {.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 16}
                            Parallel.ForEach(MailToDownload.GetConsumingPartitioner(), options, Sub(item) doSomething(item))
                          End Sub)
End Sub
```

I'm thinking I should just handle all exceptions by loading them into another blockingcollection and spawn a different thread to handle those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up putting the exceptions into a blocking collection and put a timer in another thread to periodically process the exceptions. It works quite well in a situation where the processing on the blocking collection never ends.

Answer (score 0):

Btw, why dont you catch that exception in that Parallel.Foreach "doSomething" method?
Sure you have to synchronize access to log file or whatever then but libraries like log4net do this (synchronization) for you.

FYI, if the logging was just an example and you want to perform more complex logic under some conditions when email is sent you can have a look here: https://gist.github.com/3746240
This is producer/consumer queue implementation (from book "C# 5.0 in a Nutshell: The Definitive Reference") which wraps all jobs in Tasks. Since we have Task you can easilly append ContinueWith() with potential predicate that it has to be invoked only in case of error ...

Comment: because my work requires us to use a retarded service framework, I have to do some very strange things. In the end, I'm trying to record my exceptions at the top level so that I can pass it to the framework to handle.

Comment: just have a look at code i referenced and append continuations to Enqueue() result like this: pcq.Enqueue(()=>DoSomething()).ContinueWith(()=>HandleException(), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted)

Comment: as far as I can tell, that doesn't address exceptions that would occur in a parallel.foreach in a producer consumer pattern that doesn't end. Ideally, if an error occurs, the mail is saved to disk, the error is reported, but the program continues to process the next mail message. My main concern at this point is the part where the error is reported, but the program continues.